# Duplicates Rows

Tags: jquery, keypress, keyup

I am adding additional table row upon user hitting on the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

Below code is acting strange. It adds rows depending on how many times a key is pressed when the key is in the input field.
I only want to add a row if <kbd>enter</kbd> is hit.

Can anybody tell me what is wrong with the below code?

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#quantity_sold', function () {
    var num = 0;
    console.log('key pressed');
    $(this).keypress(function (e) {
        var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
        if (code == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            quantitySold = $("#quantity_sold").val();
            rowTotal = parseInt(quantitySold) * unitPrice;
            row = "";
            insertRow();
            console.log("Num inside if statement:" + num);

            $("#inventory_name").val("");
            $("#quantity_sold").val("");
            $("#inventory_name").focus();
            return false;
        }
        console.log("Num outside of if statement:" + num);
        num++;
    });
});
```

---

Struggling with this at least 1 week and I found the problem the second I pasted the code here.

I just removed  $(this).keypress(function(e){ this line. That's all I needed to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're binding a `keypress` event to `#quantity_sold` each and every time you `keypress`.  This is why the number of events that fire continues to increase.  Don't do that.  This should do exactly what you need if you just remove the `$(this).keypress(function(e){` wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of duplicate inner keypress event handler. Modify your code to:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#quantity_sold").keypress(
            function (event) {

            var num = 0;
            console.log('key pressed');

            var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);

            if(code == 13){
                e.preventDefault();
                quantitySold= $("#quantity_sold").val();
                rowTotal = parseInt(quantitySold) * unitPrice;
                row = "";
                insertRow();
                console.log("Num inside if statement:" + num);

                $("#inventory_name").val("");
                $("#quantity_sold").val("");
                $("#inventory_name").focus();
                return false;
            }
          console.log("Num outside of if statement:" + num);
          num++;  

       }
  );

    });
```